# I just bought a new TV and now my Wiimote has a delay for its action

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-wii, monitor

So I just bought a new LCD tv that I thought would be better than my old CRT. however, I've noticed a significant delay between when I press a button during gameplay (Black Ops) and whe the action actuall takes place on screen.

It is most notable during gameplay. I have it plugged in through the component cables.

It is a Sanyo 39" LCD. What's going on and how do I fix it?

EDIT

I just noticed that some tvs have a game mode. I'm unable to find that on this tv. Also, I've read that turning off up scaling might help.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here. Are you looking for solutions as to how to minimize the delay or inquiring as to why it occurs or...?

Comment: Sorry. Both, I guess

Comment: Apologies, btw. I was typing on an ipad and it appears that the question submitted a truncated version. It made no sense to me either when I read it in its original form

Comment: Yeah, game mode is what you want.  Otherwise, you're probably looking at an input lag of 5-10 frames, compared to less than 1 (when restricting yourself to just the TV; the console has input lag as well).

Comment: @swasheck Ah, no worries, it happens, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that the Wii's signal output is analog. With newer TVs, i.e. most LCD screens, the input is digital. There's a significant delay (on the order of 4-10 frames, depending on the TV) when converting from analog to digital. This is the reason you'll see dozens of CRTs at venues for tournaments for older games like SSBM - the lag when playing on LCD screens is unacceptable.

To solve the problem, anything you can do to reduce the processing the TV has to do will help. Any settings that enhance the picture quality should be disabled for best results - ironically, this means that if your TV has a 'game mode' to disable it, because 'game mode' enhances the contrast and colour which is generally considered better for games.

Comment: Actually, you don't want to always disable game mode.  Adjusting brightness, contrast, and even colour is so cheap that well designed TVs will do it in the ADC.  Even if it isn't done in the ADC, it's fast enough to be a non-issue next to the actual analogue to digital conversion (hint: that makes up the bulk of the input lag).  Additionally, game mode will sometimes bypass a huge chunk of the image processing pipeline.

Comment: I've seen at least one LCD where the 'game mode' increased the lag. My bad generalizing that to most TVs.